# Swift implement selector in a clear way

Tags: swift2

Do I need to use selector like this every time: `#selector(MyClass.functionName)` or I just can leave it as `#selector(functionName)` what is more clear? Or maybe there are also hidden advantages of using `MyClass.functionName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Selector("methodName")` is now deprecated so you should use `Selector(Class.methodName)` if you love reliable code in this case.

The main benefits are in reducing of the typos that are made during refactoring of calling selectors. New system is type-safe and compiler can check if method is actually existing and suggest edition.